# Read lines synchronously from file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to parse a file line by line in the following format with Node.js:

```
13
13
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
9 10
0 6
7 8
9 11
5 3
```

It represents a graph. The first two lines are the number of edges and vertexes, followed by the edges.

I can accomplish the task with something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: read_stream
});
var c = 0;
var vertexes_number;
var edges_number;
var edges = [];
rl.on('line', function(line){
    if (c==0) {
        vertexes_number = parseInt(line);
    } else if (c==1) {
        edges_number = parseInt(line);
    } else {
        edges.push(line.split(' '));
    }
    c++;
})
.on('end', function(){
    rl.close();
})
```

I understand this kind of things might not be what Node.js was thought for, but the cascaded `if` in the `line` callback does not really look elegant / readable to me.

Is there a way to read synchronously lines from a stream like in every other programming language?

I'm open to use plugins if there is not a built-in solution.

[EDIT]

Sorry, I should have made clearer that **I would like to avoid loading the whole file in memory beforehand**

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

Comment: yes load it with `fs.readFileSync` and then parse it with your code synchronously after splitting by newlines i.e `lines = fs.readFileSync('graph.txt').split(/[\n\r]/);`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This project on github.com does exactly what I needed:

https://github.com/nacholibre/node-readlines

```
var readlines = require('n-readlines');
var liner = new readlines(filename);

var vertexes_number = parseInt(liner.next().toString('ascii'));
var edges_number = parseInt(liner.next().toString('ascii'));
var edges = [];
var next;
while (next = liner.next()) {
    edges.push(next.toString('ascii').split(' '));
}
```

Comment: is there a good way to do this with stdin? I am using a code submission website and cannot read /dev/stdin as a file either.

Comment: You would have better chances of getting an answer if you posted a new question with more details rather than commenting here.

Comment: Already done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638105/how-to-get-synchronous-readline-or-simulate-it-using-async-in-nodejs

Answer (score 82):

My usual code part for such simple tasks:

```
var lines = require('fs').readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter(Boolean);
```

`lines` is an array of strings without empty ones.

Comment: Thanks. However I'm still interested in lean solutions that don't load the whole file in memory.

Comment: This way can not deal with big file, such as 10000000 lines log file, because  you can load big file to memory with buffer, but nodejs toString method can not deal with too big buffer object.

Comment: It works pretty good if you have a billion txt log files each a few thousand lines long. Where each txt file is a single test execution log and you want to parse them all for relevant data and dump that data into a JSON log format for the purpose of migrating old test data into a new Kabana dashboard using an AWS ECS cluster. ;-)

Comment: dont forget `const {EOL} = require('os');` for MultiOS instead of '\n'

Comment: I really really appreciate this pinpointing answer. For just in case someone encounters "TypeError: aaa.split is not a function", using "readFileSync.toString()" can help.

Comment: @RichKS second parameter of `readFileSync` ensures that it must return a string so it'll have `.split` method.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like to use [`event-stream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) to deal with streams. It's not necessary here but I used it for the code sample. It's simple, I parse to int and put everything inside `edges`, then when the file reading is done, I take the first element wich is `vertexes_number`, the new first element is `edges_number`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var es = require('event-stream');

var filename = 'parse-file.txt';

var vertexes_number, edges_number;
var edges = [];

fs.createReadStream(filename)
    .pipe(es.split()) // split by lines
    .pipe(es.map(function (line, next) {
        // split and convert all to numbers
        edges.push(line.split(' ').map((n) => +n));

        next(null, line);
    })).pipe(es.wait(function (err, body) {
        // the first element is an array containing vertexes_number
        vertexes_number = edges.shift().pop();

        // the following element is an array containing edges_number
        edges_number = edges.shift().pop();

        console.log('done');
        console.log('vertexes_number: ' + vertexes_number);
        console.log('edges_number: ' + edges_number);
        console.log('edges: ' + JSON.stringify(edges, null, 3));
    }));
```

Comment: This is the best method so far if you don't need to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: Yes, it is very good this method, but still async, the questions states sync mode, not useful for this case though.

Answer (score 3):

Why not read them all into an array and then take out the first two elements with splice. I assume that your example is much simplified or else you would just read the whole file into memory and split it. If your actual case stores multiple graphs and you want to do something when each one is loaded for instance, you can put a test in your line event

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: read_stream
});

var buffer = [];

rl.on('line', function(line){
    buffer.push(line.split(' '));
    //Not sure what your actual requirement is but if you want to do 
    //something  like display a graph once one has loaded
    //obviously need to be able to determine when one has completed loading
    if ( buffer.length == GRAPHLENGTH) {  //or some other test
        displayGraph(buffer);
        buffer = [];
    }    
})
.on('close', function(){
    //or do it here if there is only one graph
    //displayGraph(buffer);
    rl.close();
})

function displayGraph(buffer){
    var vertexes_number = parseInt(buffer.splice(0,1));
    var edges_number = parseInt(buffer.splice(0,1));
    var edges = buffer;

    //doYourThing(vertexes_number, edges_number, edges);
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that in case of file system there is no `end` event but rather `close` is emited upon the end of the file.

Comment: Is this example synchonous? on 'line' and on 'end' are asynchronous, or not?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269197/79079), Node 11 added an async iterator syntax that makes this super simple:

```js
let c = 0
for await (const line of rl) {
  parseLine(c, line)
  c++
}
```

You can apparently also use the same iterator manually to read a single line at a time if you, for instance, wanted to read the first two header lines of your file separately:

```js
const it = rl[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
const line1 = await it.next() // { value: "...", done: false }
const line2 = await it.next() // { value: "...", done: false }
const vertex_count = parseInt(line1.value)
const edge_count = parseInt(line2.value)

let result
do {
  result = await it.next()
  parseEdge(result.value)
} while (!result.done)
```