# How to get synchronous readline, or "simulate" it using async, in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, readline

I am wondering if there is a simple way to get "synchronous" readline or at least get the appearance of synchronous I/O in node.js

I use something like this but it is quite awkward

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

var i = 0;
var s1 = '';
var s2 = '';

rl.on('line', function(line){
    if(i==0) { s1 = line; }
    else if(i==1) { s2 = line; }
    i++;
})

rl.on('close', function() {
    //do something with lines
})'
```

Instead of this I would prefer if it were as easy as something like

```
var s1 = getline(); // or "await getline()?"
var s2 = getline(); // or "await getline()?"
```

Helpful conditions:

(a) Prefer not using external modules or /dev/stdio filehandle, I am submitting code to a code submission website and these do not work there

(b) Can use async/await or generators

(c) Should be line based

(d) Should not require reading entire stdin into memory before processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js: readSync from stdin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430939/node-js-readsync-from-stdin)

Comment: @supersam654 I added some extra conditions to de-duplicate. My condition is to allow reading (single) lines using the getline type function using the readline interface in a clean "synchronous" way or to simulate this using "async/await" functions.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Just in case someone stumbles upon here in future**

**Node 11.7** added [support for this](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator) using `async await`

```
const readline = require('readline');
//const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin, //or fileStream 
  output: process.stdout
});

for await (const line of rl) {
  console.log(line)
}
```

Remember to wrap it in `async function(){}` otherwise you will get a *reserved_keyword_error*.

```
const start = async () =>{
    for await (const line of rl) {
        console.log(line)
    }
}
start()
```

To read an individual line, you can use the `async` iterator manually

```
const it = rl[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
const line1 = await it.next();
```

Comment: Can I call get a single line using this method? For example, i was thinking before the loop I want to read one or two lines, so I wanted to say like const header = await rl.next() but this did not work even in node 11.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556535/nodejs-readline-only-read-the-first-2-lines @ColinD

Comment: I find the syntactic complexity of those answers to be unnecessarily complex. I know it is perfectly doable but I'm looking for something simple like `var h1 = await rl.next(); var h2 = await rl.next(); for await (const line of rl) { /* process rest of file */ }` but as I mentioned above the rl iterator does not provide for that it seems

Comment: oh! i get it, vl check the implementation of readline and `for await `

Comment: @AishwatSingh When I use your code, I get a syntax error on the line with the await. Unexpected token, expected ( Can you verify that it is working still?

Comment: @NakulTiruviluamala I just tried it out, it works. Can you add a snippet of breaking line?

Comment: @AishwatSingh ` const line1 = await rl.next(); `  produces error `TypeError: rl.next is not a function` node 14.4

Comment: @ColinD just tried it out in `v14.4.0` still works, did you wrap it in async?

Comment: ```
const readline = require("readline");
//const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin, //or fileStream
  output: process.stdout,
});

(async () => {
  const line1 = await rl.next();
  const line2 = await rl.next();

  console.log("hi", line1, line2);
})();
```
produces (node:1798580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: rl.next is not a function

Comment: @ColinD think you need this 
```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin, 
    output: process.stdout,
});
const start = async () => {
    const it = rl[Symbol.asyncIterator]()
    const line1 = await it.next()
    const line2 = await it.next()
    console.log("hi", line1, line2);
};
start()
```


Also this may help https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line

Comment: Thanks that is great. Would you be interested in adding this as an addendum to your answer? I could accept your answer then

Answer (score 44):

You can just wrap it in a promise -

```
const answer = await new Promise(resolve => {
  rl.question("What is your name? ", resolve)
})
console.log(answer)
```

Comment: Most elegant answer!

Answer (score 30):

Like `readline` module, there is another module called `readline-sync`, which takes synchronous input.

## Example:

```
const reader = require("readline-sync"); //npm install readline-sync
let username = reader.question("Username: ");
const password = reader.question("Password: ",{ hideEchoBack: true });
if (username == "admin" && password == "foobar") {
    console.log("Welcome!")
}
```

Comment: This should be the right answer for this question (it's the best practice)

Comment: @johannchopin no this is not the approach I want. I am using pipes via stdin or large datasets, not question and answer which is what that module is what readline-sync is aparently designed to do

Comment: There is another one called `readline-async` in case anybody needs promises.

Comment: @johannchopin it can't be the best practice. readline-sync is not standard. It's a dependency..

Comment: Also, `readline-sync` can be expensive since it spawns a child process internally. There is a very simple way to achieve the same effect without child process, which I outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 17):

I think this is what you want :

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin , output: process.stdout });

const getLine = (function () {
    const getLineGen = (async function* () {
        for await (const line of rl) {
            yield line;
        }
    })();
    return async () => ((await getLineGen.next()).value);
})();

const main = async () => {
    let a = Number(await getLine());
    let b = Number(await getLine());
    console.log(a+b);
    process.exit(0);
};

main();
```

Note: this answer use experimental features and need Node v11.7

Comment: This looks good, how would you setup a loop to read until the end of the input after adding those two numbers for example?

Comment: getLine will return undefined if it reaches EOF, so while (1){ let x = await getLine(); if (x === undefined) break; /* then work with x */ } should work.

Answer (score 14):

Try this. It's still not a perfect replication of a synchronous line reading function -- e.g. `async` functions still happen later, so some of your calling code may execute out of order, and you can't call it from inside a normal `for` loop -- but it's a lot easier to read than the typical `.on` or `.question` code.

```
// standard 'readline' boilerplate
const readline = require('readline');
const readlineInterface = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
});

// new function that promises to ask a question and 
// resolve to its answer
function ask(questionText) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readlineInterface.question(questionText, (input) => resolve(input) );
  });
}

// launch your program since `await` only works inside `async` functions
start()

// use promise-based `ask` function to ask several questions
// in a row and assign each answer to a variable
async function start() {
  console.log()
  let name = await ask("what is your name? ")
  let quest = await ask("what is your quest? ")
  let color = await ask("what is your favorite color? ")
  console.log("Hello " + name + "! " + 
    "Good luck with " + quest + 
    "and here is a " + color + " flower for you.");
  process.exit() 
}
```

UPDATE: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-promise implements it (source code here: https://github.com/bhoriuchi/readline-promise/blob/master/src/index.js#L192 ). It implements several other features as well, but they seem useful too, and not too overengineered, unlike some other NPM packages that purport to do the same thing. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work due to https://github.com/bhoriuchi/readline-promise/issues/5 but I like its implementation of the central function:

```
function ask(questionText) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readlineInterface.question(questionText, resolve);
  });
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Using promises leverage the power of async/await context without the need for another library. I would rather pass the readline interface as a parameter to the ask function so that you can use different interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

Using generators your example would look like this:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

var i = 0;
var s1 = '';
var s2 = '';

var iter=(function* () {
    s1 = yield;
    i++;
    s2 = yield;
    i++;
    while (true) {
        yield;
        i++;
    }
})(); iter.next();
rl.on('line', line=>iter.next(line))

rl.on('close', function() {
    //do something with lines
})
```

So `yield` here acts as if it were a blocking `getline()` and you can handle lines in the usual sequential fashion.

---

**UPD**:
And an async/await version might look like the following:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

var i = 0;
var s1 = '';
var s2 = '';

var continuation;
var getline = (() => {
    var thenable = {
        then: resolve => {
            continuation = resolve;
        }
    };
    return ()=>thenable;
})();
(async function() {
    s1 = await getline();
    i++;
    s2 = await getline();
    i++;
    while (true) {
        await getline();
        i++;
    }
})();
rl.on('line', line=>continuation(line))

rl.on('close', function() {
    //do something with lines
})
```

In both of these "synchronous" versions, `i` is not used for distinguishing lines and only useful for counting the total number of them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example but it requires reading entire stdin before giving results however which is not ideal

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});


function lineiterator() {
    var currLine = 0;
    var lines = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        rl.on('line', function (line){
            lines.push(line)
        })
        rl.on('close', function () {
            resolve({
                next: function() {
                    return currLine < lines.length ? lines[currLine++]: null;
                }
            });
        })
    })
}
```

Example

```
lineiterator().then(function(x) {
    console.log(x.next())
    console.log(x.next())
})

$ echo test$\ntest | node test.js
test
test
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (and preferred) option is available in the docs. https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlquestionquery-options-callback

```
const util = require('util');
const question = util.promisify(rl.question).bind(rl);

async function questionExample() {
  try {
    const answer = await question('What is you favorite food? ');
    console.log(`Oh, so your favorite food is ${answer}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Question rejected', err);
  }
}
questionExample();
```

Comment: appreciate the feedback, but I was reading in data files, not prompting the user.

Answer (score 1):

Node v17.0.0 added a [Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#promises-api) for readline, `readline/promises`

```
const readlinePromises = require('node:readline/promises');

const rl = readlinePromises.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
}); 

const answer = await rl.question('What is your favorite food? ');
console.log(`Oh, so your favorite food is ${answer}`);
```

Comment: Drat!  I'm only ony version 16...

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how many strings you need I put them all in an Array

Don't hesitate to comment if you need a more detailed answer or if my answer is not exact :

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

var i = 0;
var strings = [];

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    // 2 lines below are in case you want to stop the interface after 10 lines
    // if (i == 9)
    //  rl.close()
    strings[i] = line
    i++
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log(strings)
})
// this is in case you want to stop the program when you type ctrl + C
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    rl.close()
})
```

Comment: This requires reading entire stdin into memory, I would prefer this is not the case because I read large files via stdin and needs streaming

Comment: it is a stream, so the only reason it goes into memory is because I put it in the variable strings, but if you do something else with it it won't go into memory

Comment: I understand. But I want something like in perl `my $line = <>`. Or getline in c++. Is that so hard? I feel like my request is not so outlandish and I visualize it being completed with generators or async/await

Comment: The real question is what do you want to do with all the lines?

Comment: Currently the lines of data are piped into the program via stdin, and the data generally has some header lines and then a lot of data. There are no signals for the header, you just infer it as needed by the problem, and the data and header contain a mix of strings and numbers. Therefore it is much easier to just have control over a getline function than to tweak code inside the on('line') callback.

Comment: I understand what type of data will be streamed to the interface now. However, I don't see how it would me much easier than the getline function, the `on('line', callback)` is actually not a "tweak" code since this is nodejs native. Can you try to explain what is the behaviour that you want, or if you can't, can you explain what do you mean by "control" over a getline function?

Comment: When I use this callback technique, I have to add unnecessary "if(line==1) ... if(line==2) ...." statements inside on('line', function() { }) to selectively parse header lines, that seems very awkward. I would rather have "control" over when I grab a line from stdin using a simple "var line = getline()" or "var line = lines.next()" (generator style) or "var line = await getline()" (async/await style)

Answer (score 0):

We can use promise and process.stdin events together to simulate a synchronous input system

```
const { EOL } = require("os");
const getLine = async () =>
    (
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            process.stdin.on("data", (line) => {
                resolve("" + line);
            });
        })
    ).split(EOL)[0];

const line = await getLine();
console.log(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a way to achieve this synchronously without wrapping everything around async or spawning child processes like how it's done inside `readline-sync` npm module which is expensive.
The key is to utilize the synchronous file system API, which `stdin` is compatible with.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const getchar = function(){
    // Allocate a temp buffer. This can be declared outside this function to be reused.
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1);
    // Read a single character from stdin to the temp buffer
    fs.readSync(0/*File descriptor for stdin*/, buffer, 0, 1);
    return buffer[0];
};

const readline = function(){
    let c;
    const buff = [];
    // Read characters one by one until encountering newline
    while((c = getchar()) !== '\n'.charCodeAt(0)){
        buff.push(c);
    }
    // Convert the buffer to string
    return Buffer.from(buff).toString("utf8");
};

const prompt = function(pmt){
    process.stdout.write(pmt);
    return readline();
};

const age = prompt("your age: ");
console.log(`You are ${age} years old`);
const name = prompt("your name: ");
console.log(`Your name is ${name}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple synchronous readline implementation (idea from martian17) as a JavaScript module. If you, e.g., read 2 lines, then close, it won't have read the entire file. It works whether or not your file is terminated with a newline. It strips \r chars from strings, but does not trim whitespace from each line (easy to do, though):

```
export let undef = undefined;   // a synonym
export let defined = (x) => (x !== undef)

let lookahead = undef;
let ungetc = (ch) => lookahead = ch;

let buffer = Buffer.alloc(1);

export let getc = (fd) => {

    if (defined(lookahead)) {
        let ch = lookahead;
        lookahead = undef;
        return ch;
        }

    if (fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, 1) == 1) {
        let ch = String.fromCharCode(buffer[0]);
        return (ch == '\r') ? getc(fd) : ch;
        }
    else {
        return undef;
        }
    }

export let readline = (fd) => {

    let ch = getc(fd);
    if (!defined(ch)) {
        return undef;   // no more lines
        }
    else if (ch === '\n') {
        // --- normally means an empty line
        //     unless there's nothing past it
        ch = getc(fd);
        if (!defined(ch)) {
            return undef;
            }
        ungetc(ch)
        return '';
        }
    let lChars = [];
    while (ch && (ch != '\n')) {
        lChars.push(ch);
        ch = getc(fd);
        }
    return lChars.join('');
    }
```

NOTES: Don't forget, it's synchronous. You need a lookahead to correctly handle a final `\n` which shouldn't cause an empty line to be returned. To know if it's a final `\n`, you have to read the following character and if it's there, you need to remember it for the next call to readline(). getc()
will never return a carriage return character - if it finds one, it calls itself recursively. There are other ways to handle that, but I love recursive functions. Also, it exports several things you might find handy, but the readline() function is enough. You can use it like this:

```
import fs from 'node:fs';
import {readline, defined} from './readline.js';

let fd = fs.openSync('./test/readline3.txt');
let line = readline(fd);
while (defined(line)) {
    console.log(`LINE: '${line}'`);
    line = readline(fd);
    }
fs.close(fd);
```

though, as I said, you can simply read some fixed number of lines, then close the file descriptor.

Comment: I have to admit that this code, along with a lot of the code on this page, has a problem. It assumes that 1 byte = 1 character. That's not true for most foreign languages, e.g. Chinese. If you want to use any of the code on this page, I urge you to test it with Chinese characters (you can easily get some by using translate.google.com, i.e. Google Translate). Personally, I switched back to using the n-readlines npm package.