# Simple CLI calculator in js (least amount of code, using built-in functions only)

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, calculator

I'm trying to build the following calculator in every language and js raises questions.

This is my calculator in python3 that just works in 2 lines using the built-in eval() function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
while True:
    print(eval(input("Calculate: "))
```

[image]

My goal is to reproduce this calculator with the **least amount of code and only using the built-in functions** of the given language.

I'm a rookie in js and this is how far I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
while(true){
    console.log(eval(prompt("Calculate: ")));
}
```

This is only working in theory and I understand that if I use Node as an interpreter I need to import prompt() and eval() functions to work but I'd like to avoid that because they aren't built-in and I thought I'd ask here first about the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval is already a native part of nodejs. Prompt, however, is not so simple, unfortunately. [There is no trivial way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638105/how-to-get-synchronous-readline-or-simulate-it-using-async-in-nodejs). I'd recommend to use a minimal library like [prompt-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) instead.